# Is there a PCIE to USB 3.0 converter?

Tags: usb, gpu, pci-express

I have an old desktop, which contains an old Nvidia GPU that I would like to use with my new laptop.

I have 1 USB 3.0 slot on my laptop, and the GPU requires a PCIE slot.

So my question is: **Is there a PCIE to USB 3.0 converter I could use?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Desktop GPUs are not designed to be used in the way you want to use them.  External GPUs do exist.  Additionally even if there was a PCIE to USB 3.0 convert, it wouldn't power the device, USB 3.0 cannot provide enough power for most interal desktop GPUs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are PCIE to USB3.0 converters, but there are not USB3.0 to PCIE converters. In other words, you can plug a USB host card into a PCI-E slot, but you can't connect a PCI-E device over USB. You wouldn't want to anyhow - USB 3 is 5 GBit/s max, PCI-E 2.0 x16 is 8 GB/s. When you add in the significant lag you would get from converting the signal, it wouldn't be acceptable for graphics performance.